# How to get Peer Pressure badge if we respect SE rules from the start?

Tags: discussion, badges

I believe and I like how SE sites are built. I like the gamification around the moderation, quality and participation.

But ... if someone respects rules, try their best for the quality and experience shared, and wants to "Platinum" every badge, how do they get the "Peer Pressure" badge?

> Delete own post with score -3 or lower

So, does it mean they should post a low quality answer just to get the badge or am I thinking the wrong way?

I think it would be a bad practice but in some way, it can encourage to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been discussed at [Please get rid of the peer pressure badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231270/please-get-rid-of-the-peer-pressure-badge)

I would prefer that there was no badge with that criteria for the reasons you provide and that were provided in the Meta SE question, so I wrote an [answer there supporting that position](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379745/215590).